# How to install earlier version of Phoenix with Mix CLI?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, asdf-vm

Can't install earlier Phoenix version (eg. 1.3.4) than latest stable (eg. 1.4.0) with **mix archive.install** command.

Solution not achieved according to this thread:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2991

```
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.3.4
** (Mix) No matching version for phx_new 1.3.4 (from: mix.exs) in registry

The latest version is: 1.4.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to install some earlier Phoenix versions along Latest Release in [ASDF](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) Version Manager.

Following CLI command installed only latest release (eg. 1.4.0-dev.0):

```
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.4.0-dev.0
```

**Get an workaround to install any specific earlier Phoenix Releases (eg. 1.3.4) with following CLI commands:**

```
$ mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new-1.3.4.ez
```

*PS. Solution helped me to install different Phoenix versions with different ASDF Elixir versions.*

**eg.**

- *Elixir: 1.7.4, Phoenix: 1.4.0-dev.0*
- *Elixir: 1.7.0, Phoenix: 1.3.4*